# How many interrupts and context switches good for the server?

Tags: performance, monitoring

[Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) has chart 'interrupts and context switches on the system'.

As far as this is a monitoring tool I assume these values are important for the server performance.

So, the question is: how can I know for each particular server the values are OK or too high?

I assume any Linux at least

Comment: "How long is a piece of string?"

Comment: What @lcd047 is trying to say is: it all depends on your system and your needs. If it is something like an automatic defibrillator than you want context switches and interrupts so a patient doesn't die.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monitor the trends over time and look for anomalies.  The "normal" values differ depending on the type of application load and in turn, what the application does on a regular basis.

Comment: And just for example i have linux machines with jboss and <1000 CS/s But other have >50k CS/s and for both of them this is normal